# AWS Lambda Play Scala project with VPC throws UnknownHostException

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I am trying to run a scala Play application as an AWS Lambda function based on the example [here](https://github.com/Enalmada/play-lambda-sample)
The class is a simple function:

```
 class PlayTask {

  // AWS Lambda Handler
  def exec(event: S3Event): String = WithApplication { App =>
    Play.current.configuration.getString("Play.Lambda.Greet").getOrElse("")
  }

  private def WithApplication[A](f: Application => A): A = {
    val env = Environment(new java.io.File("."), getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Prod)
    val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(env)
    val app = ApplicationLoader(context).load(context)
    try {
      Play.start(app)
      f(app)
    } finally {
      Play.stop(app)
    }
  }
}
```

The jar is loaded onto S3 container and connected to VPC for access to RDS and internet.
However on connecting with VPC and running S3 put test I get the following error.

```
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:62) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:984) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies$$FastClassByGuice$$2a7177aa.invoke(<generated>) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:57) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:91) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:174) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:108) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:174) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) [task/:na] 
 at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) [task/:na] 
 at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126) [task/:na] 
 at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93) [task/:na] 
 at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21) [task/:na] 
 at example.PlayTask.WithApplication(PlayTask.scala:16) [task/:na] 
 at example.PlayTask.exec(PlayTask.scala:9) [task/:na] 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:439) [lambda-sandbox.jar:na] 
 at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:370) [lambda-sandbox.jar:na] 
 at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:972) [lambda-sandbox.jar:na] 
 at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:231) [lambda-sandbox.jar:na] 
 at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:59) [lambda-sandbox.jar:na] 
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_71] 
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [na:1.8.0_71] 
 at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:93) [runtime/:na] 
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-0-77-249: unknown error 
 at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_71] 
 at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
```

What I understand from the java.net.UnknownHostException is that the function cannot find the hostname of localhost and fall back onto local loopback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error was on AWS side. After yesterday's downtime from AWS on the Lambda functions the error has gone away. Though I am very curious what was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

> The jar is loaded onto S3 container and connected to VPC for access to
>   RDS and internet.

When you enabled VPC access you actually disabled access to anything outside the VPC. You didn't give the Lambda function internet access by enabling the VPC, you actually removed internet access. In addition, the function no longer has access to the AWS API servers, which is why you are getting that error when trying to access S3. You should read the "Things to Know" section at the end of [this blog post announcing VPC support for Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/).

If you want the Lambda function to have access to the internet and AWS APIs and everything else outside your VPC, then you need to add a [NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to your VPC.

If you only want to add S3 access to your Lambda function there is an additional option of using an [S3 VPC Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have already enabled access to the internet and AWS APIs by adding the NAT gateway to my VPC. It was corroborated by AWS support who confirmed the configuration is correct. Is there any other reason that could cause the above error?